# WSO2 EI - Insert to Database Restrictions - DBReport Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have an api that will parse and insert 20000+ rows into an oracle db table, using the DBReport Mediator. My api code:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AllMembers" context="/AllMembers">
       <resource methods="GET">
          <inSequence>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <http uri-template="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
                   <property name="Authorization" value="Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" scope="transport"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <dbreport useTransaction="true">
                <connection>
                   <pool>
                      <dsName>xxxxxxxxx</dsName>
                   </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                   <sql>DELETE FROM MEMBERS_API_TBL </sql>
                </statement>
             </dbreport>
             <foreach id="foreach_1" expression="//jsonObject">
                <sequence>
                   <dbreport useTransaction="true">
                      <connection>
                         <pool>
                            <dsName>xxxxxxxxx</dsName>
                         </pool>
                      </connection>
                      <statement>
                         <sql>INSERT INTO MEMBERS_API_TBL VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)</sql>
                         <parameter expression="//status" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//xxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//account_id" type="NUMERIC"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//fields//xxxxx" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="//member_id" type="NUMERIC"/>
                         <parameter expression="//email" type="VARCHAR"/>
                         <parameter expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                      </statement>
                   </dbreport>
                </sequence>
             </foreach>
             <respond/>
          </outSequence>
       </resource>
    </api>
```

When I execute I get ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded, my default db OPEN Cursor limit is 1000, but I have to insert 20K+ rows, is there a way we could do this in WSO2 EI without modifying the Database Open Cursor Limit.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set the  to "False" It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue a few weeks back. Unfortunately, no DB allow more than 1000 inserts per run by using Insert into Values syntax.

Instead, I used Insert into (columnames) Select 'columnOne', 'columnTwo',....'columnN' UNION ALL Select 'columnOne', 'columnTwo',....'columnN' .....

Here, each select statement contains the column values, and multiple row inserts are joined by UNION ALL.

```
  <iterate continueParent="true" expression="$body//*[local-name()='rootElement']" sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <property expression="//ColumnOne//text()" name="ColumnOne" scope="default" type="STRING" />
              <property expression="//ColumnTwo/text()" name="ColumnTwo" scope="default" type="STRING" />
              <property expression="//ColumnN/text()" name="ColumnN" scope="default" type="STRING" />
              <property name="Quotes" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'" />
              <filter regex="false" source="boolean(get-property('operation','concat-data'))">
                 <then>
                    <property expression="fn:concat('Insert into TableName(ColumnOne,ColumnTwo,....,ColumnN) values ','(',get-property('Quotes'),get-property('ColumnOne'),get-property('Quotes'),',',get-property('Quotes'),get-property('ColumnTwo'),get-property('Quotes'),',',get-property('Quotes'),get-property('ColumnN'),get-property('Quotes'),')')" name="concat-data" scope="operation" type="STRING" />
                 </then>
                 <else>
                    <property expression="fn:concat(get-property('operation','concat-data'),',','(',get-property('Quotes'),get-property('ColumnOne'),get-property('Quotes'),',',get-property('Quotes'),get-property('ColumnTwo'),get-property('Quotes'),',',get-property('Quotes'),get-property('ColumnN') ,get-property('Quotes'),')')" name="concat-data" scope="operation" type="STRING" />
                 </else>
              </filter>
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </iterate>
     <property expression="get-property('operation','concat-data')" name="BulkInsertQuery" scope="default" type="STRING" />
```

You can extract the property  BulkInsertQuery inside your db mediator query as a parameter.

Comment: I resolved this with setting 
<dbreport useTransaction="false">
I am not aware of other databases, in Oracle it opens a Pl/SQL cursor internally to write into Database, if your are not writing DML to multiple tables, you can set this to "false" so that there is one cursor open to insert multiple rows into the target table.